# Attempted import error: 'Wallet' is not exported from '@project-serum/anchor'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, solana

Trying to import the Wallet class but getting error in title at runtime. This issue apparently should have been fixed in v0.21+ but it doesn't appear to work in my codebase.

Using nextjs v11.0.1 and @project-serum/anchor v0.23.0

Relevant snippet from index.tsx

```
import { Provider, Program, Wallet } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';

const Page = () => {
 const testWallet = new Wallet(Keypair.generate());
 return <div></div>;
}
```

The above snippet DOES work when using @project-serum/anchor v0.16.2

next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@blocto/sdk',
  '@project-serum/sol-wallet-adapter',
  '@solana/wallet-........,
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  target: 'serverless',
  distDir: 'build',
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpack5: false,
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        },
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
    );
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets'),
    };
    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty',
    };

    return config;
  },
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "module": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "assets/*": ["./public/assets/*"],
      "@solana/*": ["./node_modules/@solana/*"]
    },
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Your nextjs config file is missing an apostrophe. Is that just a transcription error from adding it into the post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, not exactly sure if this is the same issue I had, but you can try to just re-create the Wallet type locally and imports it.

Looks like this for me

```
export class MyWallet implements Wallet {

    constructor(readonly payer: Keypair) {
        this.payer = payer
    }

    async signTransaction(tx: Transaction): Promise<Transaction> {
        tx.partialSign(this.payer);
        return tx;
    }

    async signAllTransactions(txs: Transaction[]): Promise<Transaction[]> {
        return txs.map((t) => {
            t.partialSign(this.payer);
            return t;
        });
    }

    get publicKey(): PublicKey {
        return this.payer.publicKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: returning this TS error: 
Class 'MyWallet' incorrectly implements interface 'Wallet'.
  Type 'MyWallet' is missing the following properties from type 'Wallet': name, url, icon, adapter

Comment: above error due to auto importing Wallet from` @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets` instead of `@project-serum/anchor`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had to import `Wallet` like this in react

```
const { Wallet } = require("@project-serum/anchor");
```

Comment: Wallet is returning undefined for me. Perhaps due to using nextjs?

Comment: Nvm, import Provider, Program with require does not err. Just the Wallet is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs across this issue on NextJS 14, it is due to Webpack trying to bundle `@coral-xyz/anchor`, which uses NodeJS features.

Till Anchor is compatible, we can opt-it out of bundling by setting the below in `next.config.mjs`:

```json
experimental: {
  serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["@coral-xyz/anchor"],
},
```

More info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverComponentsExternalPackages

Answer (score 0):

Using `"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.14.0",`

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';

anchor.web3.Keypair.generate().publicKey
anchor.web3.Keypair.generate().secretKey
```

Looks like, in that version that you are using, `Wallet` is not available and before, `web3` was part of `@project-serum/anchor`. Then, they moved it into a separete package `@solana/web3.js`.

Solana dev tools reminds me of the beginning of solidity. Since it is  a new and demanding technology, It changes rapidly

Comment: I don't have issues with generating Keypairs. The issue is with importing `Wallet` from anchor. Also, this issue appears in versions > 0.20.0

Answer (score 0):

Use NodeWallet instead of Wallet

import { Provider, Program, NodeWallet } from '@project-serum/anchor';

Comment: also use AnchorProvider instead of Provider

Comment: Could you please provide a bit of context on both NodeWallet vs Wallet and AnchorProvider vs Provider usage?

Comment: Kindly check this https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/commit/537d470954a8d251cb69b1b44de30cec527386ea

Comment: Module '"@project-serum/anchor"' declares 'NodeWallet' locally, but it is not exported.